Resistances to two batteries where the bat1_pos + bat1_neg = bat2_pos + bat2_neg? But, bat1_pos is shorter than bat2_pos
SOK makes a unit called "12-Slot Outdoor Insulated Battery Rack – Fits SOK & EG4 Batteries"
In this configuration there are two batteries next to each other stacked six sets deep. Both batteries next to each other share the same poles. They're configured like this, notice Battery 1 has a long positive connecting cable, and a short negative. And Battery 2 has a long negative connecting cable, and a short positive cable.
               SOK RACK
                 ----------------------
  ++++++++++++++++++++++              -
  +     ----------     ++++++++++     -
  +     -        -     +        +     -
[BATTERY 1]    |NEG| |POS|    [BATTERY 2]

You can see a picture of this here
They claim the alternative, two sets of bus bars,

"[if we had two sets of bus bars it wouldn't] give us equal distance to each battery, you have a jumper between the bus bars in the middle."

My question is whether or not this configuration will mean all batteries will have the same resistance? The alternating longer-positive on batteries on the left, and longer-negative on batteries on the right satisfy the goal of "equal distance to each battery"? Does this mean they'll all charge and discharge at the same rate?

In a well-designed system, the resistance of the interconnecting wiring will be trivial in comparison to the internal cell voltages. I.e. the cells will charge equally. That said, it's a $1900 system so someone from the company should be paid well enough to say "yes".

true but meaningless. The guy said he "didn't like 2 bus bars" and suggested something linearly symmetrical and they went with it. Maybe he has OCD, or he could be bragging or marketing the distinction, but the whole thing is rather bikeshedding anyway since miniscule individual differences in rate between cells don't matter to system output, efficiency,  or cell longevity.
